# Copy object from one array of objects to another in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this.props.person like this:

```
person = [{id: 1, name: John, age: 20},
          {id: 2, name: Kate, age: 30},
          {id: 3, name: Mike, age: 25}]
```

And I have empty this.state.newPerson: [].

Function get id value, searching object with this id in this.props.person, and add to this.state.newPerson this object. It can be repeats a few times.

For example: I call funcion addPerson twice with id=1 and id=3. In result I should get

```
this.state.newPerson: [{id: 1, name: John, age: 20}, {id: 3, name: Mike, age: 25}].
```

I tried:

```
addPerson(idPerson) {    
    const list = this.state.newPerson;
    const personToList = this.props.person.find(el => el.id === idPerson);
    const newP = Object.assign(list, { personToList });    
    this.setState({ newPerson: newP });
  }
```

In fact, I got something like **[personToList {id: ...}]**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign is used to combine two javascript object.personToList is already an object.

```
const newP = Object.assign(list, personToList);
```

Actually,you could use push to fix it.

```
const newP = list.push(newP)
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you use Object.assign if this.state.newPerson is an array?
Just use 
`list.push(personToList)` but set your state like this `this.state.newPerson = [];`

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `personToList` to the `list` array instead of assigning the entire array with the object `{ personToList: personToList }`.

You could use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { newPerson: [] };

  addPerson = personId => {
    const list = this.state.newPerson;

    if (list.some(el => el.id === personId)) {
      return;
    }

    const personToList = this.props.person.find(el => el.id === personId);
    const newP = [...list, personToList];

    this.setState({ newPerson: newP });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <div>
          {this.props.person.map(p => (
            <div id={p.id} onClick={() => this.addPerson(p.id)}>
              {p.name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.newPerson.map(p => (
            <div id={p.id} onClick={() => this.addPerson(p.id)}>
              {p.name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    person={[
      { id: 1, name: "John", age: 20 },
      { id: 2, name: "Kate", age: 30 },
      { id: 3, name: "Mike", age: 25 }
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.assign is not right for this use case scenario. You're trying to add to an array on the state.

Try this instead:

```
addPerson(idPerson) { 
  let list = [...this.state.newPerson];
  let personToList = this.props.person.find(el => el.id === idPerson);
  list.push(personToList);
  this.setState({
    newPerson: list
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns only the first matching item. Use `filter` to get all of them.

Check the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You should add actual code to your answer to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
addPerson(idPerson) { 
    this.setState({
      newPerson : this.state.newPerson.concat(this.props.person.find( i => i.id === idPerson))
    })
  }
}
```

or

```
 addPerson(idPerson) { 
    this.setState({
      newPerson : [this.state.newPerson, this.props.person.find( i => i.id === idPerson)]
    })
  }
```